# Value NAN in NetCDF4 file for lat&lon using Python

Tags: python, netcdf

I have two files in NetCDF4 (latlon and other file without latlon).

I open the two files in the same code and I choose one variable and the two variable lon and lat.
When I write lon I have the value `nan` and I don't know why.

The two files have same dimensions (size) and same dimensions for variables all I need is to show the value of lat&lon when I open the two files. How can I do it?

```
In [54]: import numpy as np
    ...: import netCDF4
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: fic1='/data/latlon_+000.0_globe.nc'
    ...: 
    ...: nc1 = netCDF4.Dataset(fic1,'r')
    ...: 
    ...: lon = nc1.variables['lon'][:]
    ...: lat = nc1.variables['lat'][:]
    ...: 
    ...: fic='/data/Mmultic3kmNC4_msg04_201905080200
    ...: .nc'
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: nc = netCDF4.Dataset(fic,'r')
    ...: IR=nc.variables['IR_108'][:]
    ...: 
    ...: 


In [55]: 

In [55]: lon
Out[55]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=1e+20,
  dtype=float32)

In [56]: lat
Out[56]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=1e+20,
  dtype=float32)

In [57]:
```

How I can get value of lat & lon?

Comment: your code seems right, could you provide your sample data for tests ?

Comment: @HichamZouarhi you can get data here  latlon[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UjTv0aYttGYoVaUUAT9gjEPuTgcOvOHj/view] and other file data [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IT-F7AbIx4bCjMLosjBx4F4UCoIX5DU0/view] thank you

Comment: there are indeed no data ( or corrupted data since many attributes of the variables are missing ) in the first file ( the one with lat lon ), are those coordinates supposed to refer to X and Y on the second file ?

Comment: yes the 2 files have same dimensions when you open the file1 latlon with the second you can get value of lon & lat i don't know how but yesterday i did it and today i can get the value :!!

Answer (score 0):

after checking the contents of the 2 files, there seems to be a problem with the dimensions of the one with lat lon variables since the attribute `current_shape = (3712, 3712)` for lat and lon while it should be `(3712,)`.

The file may be corrupted and you'll have to create it again from the X and Y attributes of the second file since they are linked.

to do so you can start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923646/how-to-create-a-netcdf-file-with-python-netcdf4) , you will also need to transform the projected coordinates to lat lon, and for that you can use [pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/)